# Cmake target_link_libraries Public, Private structure Question

Tags: cmake

So basically my question is my Cmakelists looks like this

```
project(Library)

set(LIBRARY_HEADER "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/LearnOpenGL.h"
                   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Shader/Shader.h"
)
set(LIBRARY_SOURCE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/LearnOpenGL.cpp"
                   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Shader/Shader.cpp"
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${LIBRARY_HEADER}
    ${LIBRARY_SOURCE}
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC 
        ./include
    PRIVATE
        ./src
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Packages)
```

My Question why is Shader/Shader.h able to access the external Packages named Packages
and not LearnOpenGL.h i know this is not a valid folder structure for cmake but i want to know why this is happening.

[image]

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: The information in the question post is **insufficient** for tell why your IDE thinks that given `#include`s are incorrect. First of all, configuration of include directories in IDE may be not the same as in the real project. That is, IDE may be wrong in its assumption. If actual building of your project results in an error, then show (add to the question post) the **exact error message**. That message should include path to the **source file** is compiled and chain of **headers** included by that source file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have included the SS of the output Using visual studio Ignore the OpenglUI its another test class like LearnOpenGL class

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages **images** which represents textual information. Instead, we expect the error message to be in the question post as **text**. See [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.

Comment: The error message is about compiling the file `main.cpp`, which is not part of your library. That file is most likely the part of your executable. It is absolutely irrelevant which target a *header* file belongs to. What is important to which target belongs the **source file** which is compiled. Do you link your executable target with the library?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think so i have linked it ```project(App LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    src/main.cpp
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
   PRIVATE
    ./src    
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Library)```